# Using Pi-Hole with USB Tether to Eth0 Bridge

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os, bridge, pi-hole

New to the forums. Forgive me if my first question isn't that easy to understand. I'll try my best.

For some background:

- I installed and configured pi-hole previously for an internet service that we no longer have.
- I've also setup a usb tether to eth0 whole home hotspot with my router.

Now if I wanted to setup this tether bridge for the Pi to be used like a modem between my phone's data and the router, am I able to run Pi-Hole on the raspberry without interfering with anything? I know that pi-hole uses a DNS server but the last time I plugged my pi into the router for pi-hole I plugged it into one of the other ports instead of the WAN port which I need to do for the bridge mode.